# How to prevent users from deleting records

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose i have three table called category, subcategory and prodcut and the structure of this tables are

```
           category

 ====Catid=======CatName=====   
 |     1     |    DRESS    |
 |     2     |    FOOD     |




                  subcategory

 ====SubCatid=======SubCatName========Catid=====
 |     1     |    cake          |       2      |
 |     2     |    t-shirt       |       1      |
 |     3     |    chocolate     |       2      |
 |     4     |    shirt         |       1      |



                        product

 ====productid=======productName========SubCatid=====
 |     1        |    p1            |       2        |
 |     2        |    p2            |       1        |
 |     3        |    p3            |       1        |
 |     4        |    p4            |       2        |
```

Now I want to make my application like this that if any of the category present on subcategory table as a record user cant delete this category. User have to delete it from subcategory table, after that User can delete it from category table. At that same time User also cant delete the record from subcategory which is present in product table. I tried with Foreignkey but I cant understand the proper way to solve this. Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Foreign Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) with RESTRICT reference option:

```
alter table `subcategory` add foreign key (`Catid`) references `category`(`Catid`) on update cascade on delete restrict
```

So if somebody will try to remove a category that has subcategories, MySQL will forbid that and output error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Same thing for products table:

```
alter table `product` add foreign key (`SubCatid`) references `subcategory`(`SubCatid`) on update cascade on delete restrict
```

Comment: and add same thing on product table also? like if i delete subcategory and it present in product table, it also can be deleted?